# jQuery input value switching

Tags: jquery, html, input

I've been using this code to switch the value of my inputs onFocus and Blur:

```
$('input, textarea').focus(function() {
            value=$(this).val();
            $(this).attr("value","")};
        });
        $('input, textarea').blur(function() {
            if($(this).val()=="") {
                $(this).val(value);
            }
        });
```

Only problem is, when I type something into these inputs, then refocus after typing into another, the field goes blank. Is there a way to edit this code to inhibit this?

[Example for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/EMYmG/) :)

---

I tried something like this, but it didn't have the effect I desire:

```
$('input, textarea').focus(function() {
            value=$(this).val();
    if($(this).val(value)) {
            $(this).attr("value","");
        });
        $('input, textarea').blur(function() {
            if($(this).val()=="") {
                $(this).val(value);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the initial value and check against that..

```
$('input, textarea').each(function(){
    // initial storing of the pre-defined value
    $(this).data('initial', this.value);
}).focus(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // on focus if the value of the field is still the initial then clear it
    if ( (this.value) == $this.data('initial') )
      this.value = '';
}).blur(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // on blur if the value is still cleared then restore the initial 
    if ( (this.value) == '' )
        this.value = $this.data('initial');
})
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/EMYmG/2/

---

**Update**

You can avoid storing to the data, since there is a standard property named `defaultValue` that we can use instead. (*gets much cleaner*)

```
$('input, textarea').focus(function(){
        // on focus if the value of the field is still the initial then clear it
        if ( (this.value) == this.defaultValue )
          this.value = '';
    }).blur(function(){
        // on blur if the value is still cleared then restore the initial 
        if ( (this.value) == '' )
            this.value = this.defaultValue;
    })
```

**Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/PjsRQ/

Comment: +1, very nice! I never thought about this solution, it eliminates the issue my solution has (plus, no manual value writing in the array).

Answer (score 1):

Values are not labels. Trying to pretend they are leads to major accessibility problems.

If you really want to use this sort of design, and I urge you not to. Then position labels under the inputs and style them so they can't be seen (but still exist in the DOM for screen readers).

A [jQuery example is on my website](http://dorward.me.uk/tmp/label-work/example.html), the code is clear, but it is waiting to be properly documented.

Comment: I agree with you, but these aren't pretend labels. I didn't put the labels in the example, I wanted it as "barebones" as possible. :) sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Kyle — So you're going to have, for example, a label telling people to put a telephone number in a field, and defaulting its value to "Tel", and then getting rid of that value when the field is clicked in? This seems like a duplication of effort.

Comment: I agree, it really is a definite duplication. I wish I had control over the design.

Comment: Has the product owner seen the design mockups? Showing them a picture of `Tel: [Tel       ]` and friends might help them realise that it is a poor design :)

Comment: Haha, I have! Or I wouldn't be doing it :P

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ajcmq/

It's a very simple thing, really: if the field's value is one of the initial four, then clear it, otherwise, we assume it's been changed and we leave it alone on focus.

The only drawback is that when you use one of the four dfault values in another field, it will be emptied as well :D.

Comment: Thanks Mingos, I have no idea what my users will be typing into the boxes (company names etc) so I'll go with Gaby's. +1

Comment: Wise choice, Kyle. His answer rules :)

Answer (score 0):

The way the [jQuery Form Example plugin](http://www.pi.gov.pl/icorlib/jquery/plugins/formInput/demo.html) does this is by assigning a class to the input elements and removing it after the initial value in the elements has been changed to determine which elements have been edited after the DOM load and which still contain the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a [jQuery Hint Overlay](http://blog.jdeerhake.com/inputhintoverlay-jquery-plugin)?

http://jsfiddle.net/6y2wX/

Comment: 99% of That code is just the library. If you'll be re-using this functionality, its much better because you can "Hint-ize" a form with the one line at the bottom `$("form#test").inputHintOverlay(5, 6);`